# How to set bundle to null, once data is consumed

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-intent

I am passing data from an activity to fragment by using following code.

```
    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("seatId", seatId);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then I consume the data by using following code in my fragment.

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
    if(args!=null && args.getString("seatId")!=null){
        matchId = args.getString("seatId", "");
    }
```

Now after this I want to set bundle to null.

The issue is once I set data to fragment through bundle, it keeps it there.

Comment: Override Bundle?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, and I don't think you should need to try to remove it. Your app would break in very strange ways in low memory condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hold of the bundle or simply `getArguments().clear()` as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#clear()).